# Github: Why is my project's last release not marked as "latest release"?

Tags: github, release

According to Github docs, the last release of a project is supposed to be automatically marked as "latest release", visually and with "/releases/latest" url suffix.

[image]

https://help.github.com/articles/linking-to-releases/#linking-to-the-latest-release

Here is one example where it works.

https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/releases

https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/releases/latest

But it doesn't work in the following project. The last release is not visually marked as "latest", and the "/releases/latest" suffix doesn't work.

[image]

https://github.com/ramtob/d3-parallel-links/releases

https://github.com/ramtob/d3-parallel-links/releases/latest

Why doesn't it work here? What is missing?

Answer (score -4):

To setup a release, just go to : https://github.com/username/project/releases/new

You'll find the explications you need. To answer to your question properly, here is the "why" you don't have any release yet (quote from github).

> There aren’t any releases here
>   Releases are powered by tagging specific points of history in a repository. They’re great for marking release points like v1.0.

A release is a tagged version of your app on the branch master.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer my question. I didn't ask why I don't have releases. I do have releases. I asked why my last release is not marked, visually and as url, as "latest release".

Comment: Is your release on branch master ? Is it possible to see your project ? Because technically, "latest release" should be visible automatically on the last tagged release.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. My project is [here](https://github.com/ramtob/d3-parallel-links)

Comment: I just tried it myself https://github.com/artandor/ppe3/releases/latest and it works. Try to make your release tag via github instead of via git command. It also seems that you can select an existing tag and set it as release, put a description, a title .. Go to https://github.com/ramtob/d3-parallel-links/releases/new to do so.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that when adding a release on the github site itself, it does show "latest release". The question remains, why? I don't want to have to create releases on the github site itself. Perhaps something should be added to the git tag command.

Comment: The latest release seems to be github-side, because it's also linked to a release title and description. My last guess to you is to try something like : `git tag -d <tagname> -m <msg>` maybe github will identify your tag and set the message as description.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make a few additional tests

Comment: How did it go ?

Comment: Well, I tried to create signed tags. But for some reason I didn't manage to create them. Then I got distracted by other stuff. I will get back to this when I can...